Contraction in belief revision
I am currently looking into belief revision and am struggling with understanding the contraction postulates. In particular, recovery which states that for every belief base $K$ and sentence $\phi$ it holds that $ K \subseteq (K \dot{-} \phi) + \phi $. I am not sure how to read this postulate.
Given a belief base $K=\{p, q, q\rightarrow p\}$, the contraction $K \dot{-} p$ would be required to be either $\{q\}$ or $\{q \rightarrow p\}$, because $p$ would otherwise still be inferable. But adding $p$ to either of those belief bases would not yield a superset of $K$, because $ (K \dot{-} p) + p $ would either be $\{q, p\}$ or $\{q \rightarrow p, p\}$. So, the original premises magically reappear but it is not clear how and why that should work.
